# Mechanize for Python 3.x

Tags: python, authentication, screen-scraping, screen, mechanize

is there any way how to use Mechanize with Python 3.x?

Or is there any substitute which works in Python 3.x?

I've been searching for hours, but I didn't find anything :(

I'm looking for way how to login to the site with Python, but the site uses javascript.

Thanks in advance,

Adam.

Answer (score 3):

lxml.html provides form handling facilities and supports Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar project, but the faq for mechanize explicitly says they don't intend on supporting 3x any time soon.  Is there a reason the code has to be written in 3?

The way I'm trying to tackle the problem is by emulating the java script with form submits, it takes some reverse engineering. (which is, if the javascript ends by submitting a form, and you can find the arguments the script passes to the submit(), just follow the example from the mechanize doc

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

```
br.select_form(name="order")
# Browser passes through unknown attributes (including methods)
# to the selected HTMLForm.
br["cheeses"] = ["mozzarella", "caerphilly"]  # (the method here is __setitem__)
# Submit current form.  Browser calls .close() on the current response on
# navigation, so this closes response1
response2 = br.submit()
```