# Cannot import package - "ImportError: No module named _mechanize"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the Anaconda 2.1.0 distribution of Python on Windows 8.

```
    python --version
    Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
```

I used pip to install the mechanize package. pip (v 6.0.8) installed mechanize 0.2.5 which is the most recent release.

But, while trying to import the package, python throws an error:

```
    >>> import mechanize  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in   
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mechanize\__init__.py", line 122, in   
    from _mechanize import \
    ImportError: No module named '_mechanize'
```

Similar questions here received replies to check if the installation was done on the `PYTHONPATH`.

I also checked `sys.path` and there seems to be no problem there.

```
    >>> import sys
    >>> sys.path
    ['',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\cssselect-0.9.1-py3.4.egg',
     'C:\\Anaconda3',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\python34.zip',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.2.3-py3.4.egg',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\runipy-0.1.1-py3.4.egg',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-12.2-py3.4.egg',
     'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
     'C:\\Users\\UserName\\.ipython']
```

I am able to import other packages residing in the same directory, for e.g. numpy.

Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mechanize for Python 3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237164/mechanize-for-python-3-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Joe for pointing that out.
Mechanize is not supported for Python 3.x.
For my job, I set up a new Python 2.7 environment through `conda` and switched to it. It addressed the issue.